# How to restrict asset finder dropdown list in aem?

Tags: aem

I am trying to restrict asset finder dropdown to documents for a particular user group. Any pointers how to achieve it in AEM 6.4

Comment: So, a broader group has access to the page, but only a small set should be able to select a document. Is that right?

Comment: The way I interpret the question: a certain user group should only be able to see/select documents in the asset finder dropdown.  Other groups would be able to see/select all assets.  

@Ravi, please consider adding screenshots to make your question more descriptive and understandable.